# C# asp.net core v. 2 self hosted how to upload image to subfolder under wwwroot?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am making a self hosted asp.net core application with version 2.0

I am having problems uploading images to be displayed on the webpage.
I want the images to be placed under wwwroot, but on my windows pc, the wwwroot is located under program files/my app folder, where I need admin rights to write. (besides it being a nasty place to put the files)
How can I change the location of the wwwroot? and/or change the location of where the files are uploaded to. 
And how do I set the path in the  src to point to under wwwroot / where ever I place it on disc?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new physical file provider:

```
public class UserFilesProvider : PhysicalFileProvider
{
    public UserFilesProvider() : base(@"C:\Path\To\wwwroot") { }
}
```

Pass your physical files provider to `StaticFileOptions` in `Startup.Configure`

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new UserFilesProvider();
}
```

You will still need to grant permissions to the new folder, but this will let you assign the location of that folder.